# terraform flatten loop for 3 times

Tags: terraform

Has any one tried to get flatten for 3 loops working? I keep getting an error when i try the 3rd one:
I am trying to loop through a list within a data resource - data.instances.sg.ids
Variable example:

```
alarms = [
 {
 instances = data.instances.ids ## a list of instance ids
 config = [
  metric_name = "disk_free"
  threshold = "GreaterThan"
 ]
 }
]


locals {
  configs = flatten([
    for config_key, config_list in var.alarms : [
       for instance in config_list.instances : {
          for config in config_list.configs : {
        instance_id = instance
        metric_name  = config.name
        threshold   = config.threshold
      }
    }
    ]
  ])
}
```

how can i properly loop through and flatten this list with data instances list.

Thanks

Comment: What error? What is the example input and output? What are `var.alarms` and all other variables used?

Comment: When i add the 3rd for line, i get a:"Invalid 'for' expression: Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.HCL"

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you were getting your errors?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you want to construct, but I think it should be:

```
locals {
  configs = flatten([
    for config_key, config_list in var.alarms : [
       for instance in config_list.instances : [
          for config in config_list.configs : 
           {
            instance_id = instance
            metric_name  = config.name
            threshold   = config.threshold
           }
       ]
    ]
  ])
}
```

Comment: let me try when i have time. For now i am doing a less fancy way due to time. Thank you for following up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did get an error saying "This value does not have any attributes." (referencing the config_list.configs) But i got the solution based on your syntax.

  configs = flatten([
    for config_key, config_list in var.alarms : [
       for instance in config_list.instances : [
          for config in config_list: 
           {
            instance_id = instance
            metric_name  = config_list.metric_name
            threshold   = config_list.comparison_operator
           }
       ]
    ]
  ])
}

Comment: continue:
it's odd that config.metric_name doesn't work but config_list works for getting the attributes. It requires the 3rd for loop but it doesn't use "config" within the 3rd  for loop require you to use config_list to get the attributes.

Comment: @sdas2 The answer is a fix to your error. I don't know, nor you provided any explanation, what are all these variables in your question. So I don't know what config is your setup.

Comment: Actually, this logic with 3 for loops dont work because even if there is only 1 instance, it will loop many times depending with the same instance on the number of attributes inside. The output appears correct when only using the top 2 loops but it doesnt work when you apply it. It only creates the 1st of each instance. It appears to be a bug because it looks correct when you output the list. The symptom is that it keeps changing the instance_id.  It doesnt happen if you run this multiple resource creations but that is redundant.

Comment: Also when doing another terraform apply, it wants to do changes to each instance_id. When i run it, it gives this error:
Updating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: A separate request to update this alarm is in progress